# How to use textbox lost-focus event

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, lost-focus

I have a textbox and I want to check the data from database for duplicate record when I lost the cursor from textbox.

So please help me how to solve this.

Comment: you need the `$("#textboxid").focusout();` event.

Comment: in this can i check value database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VIPUL,

I created the following example for you. This can help you to check the data from the textbox with the data in the Database.

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Put the value to be checked with the Database in a Variable.
        var valueToCheck = textBox1.Text;

        //Create connection with the database.
        var sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Connection String to Database");

        //Create dataset instance to fill with the return results from the Database.
        var ds = new DataSet();
        //Create SqlCommand to be execute on the database.
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE 'field to be checked' = " + valueToCheck, sqlConn);
        //Create SqlDataAdapter
        var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds.Clear();
        try
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            //do you stuff here.
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks RaZor in page load event what to write?

Comment: I'm not really an ASP.NET developer. Give me some time to look it up ;)

Comment: Just found a declaration for the event, try this: 

<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" Runat="server" 
Text="" 
OnLeave="textBox1_OnLeave" />

protected void textBox1_OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //put the code that I posted earlier here!
}

Comment: in aspx page onLeave event is not whown

Answer (score 1):

This might fix your issue:

`<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" onblur="Your Function"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: in this, i think function should in js

Comment: Yes, Here is the link where I found the answer for your question:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/334142/how-to-call-onblur-client-event-in-aspx-text-box