# Monitor When textbox Text changes

Tags: vb.net, textbox, textchanged

I am working on a snippet of coding in VB.net that will notify the user when they input a value into the text box. In other words, the minute they "unfocussed" outside the textbox, my `Response.Write` will alert them that text has been added.

I thought that the code should go within :

```
`Protected Sub FED_TAX_ID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FED_TAX_ID.TextChanged`
```

However, when I input text and go to the next textbox below it, the `Response.Write` doesn't show a message pop-up.

Therefore, how do I get it show up every time a user makes a change to the text? I don't want to use a button to "submit" the changes, but rather automatically be changed by user if they decide what they typed wasn't right.

```
Protected Sub FED_TAX_ID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FED_TAX_ID.TextChanged

    If FED_TAX_ID.Text.Length <> 0 Then
        Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('ID was entered/changed');</script>")
    End if

End sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187737/how-to-use-textbox-lost-focus-event

Comment: `a snippet of coding .. that will notify the user when they input a value into the text box` wont they know because *they* input the value?

Comment: This is a dummy test. I will do something different but need to know it is working. I want to make sure the string they input fits my criteria but my code needs to continue to check the string inputted whenever their cursor leaves the textbox

Comment: @Steve I have been looking over the examples and honestly it isn't helping. The suggestions are not working with what I will do with my coding :/

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `onblur` event.  Add it to your textbox properties and it will trigger when the element loses focus.  You can compare the textbox current text value to its previous value (stored in another variable or hidden field) and then popup an alert if they don't match.  This should get you started.

```
onblur="CheckText();" 'this goes in textbox properties

<script type="text/javascript">    
function CheckText() {
    'compare values here if they don't match then 
    'alert('ID was entered/changed')
}
</script>
```

Just remember to update your variable/hiddenfield with the current textbox value after you alert the user.